# MySQL: SELECT more data than necessary or use multiple SELECT queries?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm wondering if it would be better to use a single query and SELECT more data than I might need, or use multiple queries and SELECT only what I need when I need it. For example when the client submits a username and password, my PDO query string is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM users WHERE username=:username";
```

Then in PHP I verify the submitted password against the hash. If it succeeds, I do more queries to get more data like name and address. But would it be better to add those to my initial password hash query so that I'll already have it in the likely event that the password matches? That way I'd save a query. If the password is wrong though, I'd be wasting that lookup of extra information. In general, would it be better to do less queries and get more data each time, possibly more than necessary, or to do more queries and only get exactly the data I need each time?

Comment: The answer `We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%` is at [softwareengineering.stackechange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 0):

The answer `We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%` is at [softwareengineering.stackechange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Luuk says, observe how simple the combined query is:

```
SELECT name, address
    FROM users
    WHERE username = '...'
      AND passwordHash = '...;
```

Then if you get a row (the 97% case), you are finished.  If you get no row, it is either a bad username or bad pwd.  (If you need to distinguish between those two cases, then it gets a little more complex.)

Think of the general question by looking at a Rule of Thumb:  "90% of a `SELECT` is overhead."  By that I am referring to network traffic, parsing, developing the query plan, locking, sending results back, etc.